# Searching and if statement in a hash table within powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to search a hash table that I have imported from CSV.

There are several headers in the CSV, for argument's sake, lets say
**Username, email, service, date, serverID**

I'm importing the CSV with the line below,

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv $csv | group -AsHashTable -Property Username
```

I'm looking to do an if statement in my script that will check the username and the service are present in the hash table. I already have all the variables for username and service sorted.

```
if (($username -and $service) -in ($CSVData.username -and $CSVData.service)) {
    Write-Host "some text I want" -ForegroundColor Yellow
} 
else 
{
    write-host "new entry"
}
```

Thanks for the help!
Luke

Answer (score 0):

I believe the condition you're looking for is:

```
if ($CSVData[$username].Service -eq $service) {
    Write-Host "some text I want" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
else {
    write-host "new entry"
}
```

Breaking the condition into small pieces:

- `$CSVData[$username]` gets the hash table **Value** where it's **Key** is `$username`, **if the hash table does not have an existing key for `$username`, the output is null**.
- `.Service` gets the value of the `Service` property from the returned object.
- `-eq $service` tests if the value from the `Service` property of `$username` in the hash table is equal to `$service`

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you for your help. Sorry for the long delay in responding.